# Create New Table in PHP upon form submit

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure if this is possible. What i want to do is create a new table every time a user submits a form. So far i have created my form and also insert these values into a database. I am able to echo a table of what was submitted. However, every time this form is submitted i want it to create a separate table with the new info. So it would show the previous form submission in one table and the newly submitted form data in another. How do i do this? Thank you

This is my PHP code for inserting and selecting the table:

```
$connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db=mysql_select_db('dialogue');
if($connect)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO dialogue(english1,english2,english3,english4,english5,english6,english7,english8,english9,english10,english11,english12,english13,english14,english15,english16,english17,english18,english19,english20,sanskrit1,sanskrit2,sanskrit3,sanskrit4,sanskrit5,sanskrit6,sanskrit7,sanskrit8,sanskrit9,sanskrit10,sanskrit11,sanskrit12,sanskrit13,sanskrit14,sanskrit15,sanskrit16,sanskrit17,sanskrit18,sanskrit19,sanskrit20) VALUES($english1,$english2,$english3,$english4,$english5,$english6,$english7,$english8,$english9,$english10,$english11,$english12,$english13,$english14,$english15,$english16,$english18,$english19,$english20,$sanskrit1,$sanskrit2,$sanskrit3,$sanskrit4,$sanskrit5,$sanskrit6,$sanskrit7,$sanskrit8,$sanskrit9,$sanskrit10,$sanskrit11,$sanskrit12,$sanskrit13,$sanskrit14,$sanskrit15,$sanskrit16,$sanskrit18,$sanskrit19,$sanskrit20)";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    if($query)
    {

        $sql="SELECT * FROM dialogue";

        $query=mysql_query($sql);
        if($query)
        {

            echo "<table border=1>";
            echo "<tr><th>English</th><th>Sanskrit</th><th>Root</th></tr>";
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['english1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sanskrit1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['english11'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sanskrit11'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['english2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sanskrit2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['english12'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sanskrit12'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
            echo "</table>";

        }
    }
}
}
        }

?>
```

Comment: table? database table? html table? kitchen table?

Comment: A new html table with data from the database. So for every new id, a new table. So everytime user submits, the id increments. So for every new id, new table showing data from database.

Comment: new html table!? new id of what? what id will increment?

Comment: my database has an id column which auto increments. So every time this id increments i want to create and display a new table with the data from that id along with a table from the previous form submission.

Comment: do you want a table or a row? if you want a row your code is good `logically` but contains too many `{}` for example after the while you opened 2 `{` when you only need 1

Comment: A new table, just like the one created in the code above

Comment: btw if you're still learning, learn using mysqli or PDO, mysql_* is deprecated